# "Cannot create directory" while building app post AS 3.0 upgrade

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

While running the build via ./gradlew check the build fails with the below stack trace. I have updated gradle to 4.1 and AS to 3.0 post which facing this issue.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDefaultGlobalIndiaOnlyDebug'.

  > Cannot create directory C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\apk\defaultGlobalIndiaOnly\debug\C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\apk\defaultGlobalIndiaOnly\debug\C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\apk\defaultGlobalIndiaOnly\debug
- Try: Run with `--info or --debug` option to get more log output.
- Exception is:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDefaultGlobalIndiaOnlyDebug'.
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Cannot create directory C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\apk\defaultGlobalIndiaOnly\debug\C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\ap
>   k\defaultGlobalIndiaOnly\debug\C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\apk\defaultGlobalIndiaOnly\debug
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$10(OutputScope.java:241)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:236)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:197)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:181)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:471)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>           ... 27 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create directory C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\apk\defaultGlobalIndiaOnly\debug\C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\apk\defau
>   ltGlobalIndiaOnly\debug\C:\Users\<>\<>\<>\app\build\outputs\apk\defaultGlobalIndiaOnly\debug
>           at com.android.utils.FileUtils.mkdirs(FileUtils.java:215)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:664)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:522)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(OutputScope.java:186)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(OutputScope.java:203)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$null$8(OutputScope.java:225)
>           at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:235)
>           ... 42 more

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0):

Found this @ https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Modifying variant outputs at build time may not work

Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the new plugin. It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name during build time, as shown below:

```
// If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects,
// you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates
// through only the objects that already exist during configuration time—
// but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model.
// However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are
// added during execution.

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }
```

However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing outputFile objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means faster configuration times.